# Margin collapse causing a Div to move.

Tags: html, border, margin

I am working on HTML and having an issue with what I think is margin collapse. When I take out the line "border:solid black 1px;" from the Div #body in my css, it causes the Div #header to drop about 20% on the page. I can't figure out WHY it is doing that, or how to fix it. I have tried making the body Div border 0px and it does the same thing. If I take the body Div out entirely, it does the same thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cast & Crew - Home Page</title>
<style type="text/css"> 

</style>
<link href="css2.css" type="text/css"                        
              rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="body">
<div id ="header">
    <span class="float"><img class="img" src = "face2.png" alt="Face mask"></span>
        Cast & Crew Restaurant

    <span class="floatr"><img class="img" src = "face.png" alt="Face mask"></span>


<table id="links">
<tr>
    <th><a href="Home.html"> Home</a></th>
    <th><a href="Menu.html"> Menu</a></th>
    <th><a href="plabout.html">About Us</a></th>
    <th><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class ="sidebar">
<table>
    <tr><td><a href="#app">Appetizers</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#salad">Salads</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#burger">Burgers</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#sand">Sandwiches</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#pasta">Pasta</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#entree">Entrées</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#pizza">Pizza</a></td></tr>

</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code

```
a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:visited {color:#0066FF}
a:hover {color:#3385FF;}
a:focus {color:#B20000;}
a:active {background-color: white; color:black;}

.blankrow{height: 40px !important; 
    }

#body   {height: 1150px; width: 100%;
    border:solid black 2px;}


#header     {position: fixed;
    background:black;
    height: 160px;width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
        font-size:40pt;
        text-shadow:5px 4px 10px #FF0000,-5px -4px 10px #FFFFFF;
        color:#000000;

        }

html        {background-image: url("bg.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position; 50%, 50%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        min-height:100%;
        background-size:cover;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        }

.img    {width: 50px; height:85px;}

#links  {width:50%; 
    height:50px;
    font-size:22pt;     
    margin:auto;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #000000;
    }

#menu   {height: 3200px;
    width: 900px;

    margin-top:15%;
    margin-left:17%;
    font-size:18pt;}

.sidebar {width: 150px;
    height: 230px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    top: 300px;
    font-size:18pt;
    border:solid black 2px;}

.spacer{height: 10px !important; }
```

Comment: i don't see that problem here http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2MKfw/ it's the samwe with and without border...

Comment: When I save the file in Notepad ++ and run it in Firefox, IE, Chrome or Safari, I get the issues I mentioned above.

Comment: Well did you check the fiddle? does it work? if yes the problem is  somewhere else... where is the class `float`? are you sure you shared the whole code? if the code you shared can't replicate the problem, how do we solve it?

Comment: It works in fiddle, but does not work anywhere else. Class float does not exist yet, it is there for a future addition that I have not initiated. The whole code has been shared. I don't know why it does work in the fiddle thing but not in practical application.

Comment: 'Application'? are you using any other style sheets or plugins in the 'application'? Can you replicate the problem anywhere else.. or give an online link.? open developer console  and inspect the page, check whether any styles are overridden or extra styles are being added..

Comment: http://107.21.118.23/~vancej10/pub3304/Project/

Menu2 and Menu3 show the code with and without the line
        border:solid black 2px;
under the #body in the css. The Css for both is listed there as well. More has been added to the page, but it is just table data so that doesn't affect the issue I am having.

No other style sheets or plugins being used that I am aware of. 

Not familiar with developers console. This is only my first semester working with HTML.

Comment: Applying top:0 for #header will fix the issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying top:0 for #header will fix the issue